# Storing JsonWebKey used to sign the token : JWT token based authentication

Tags: java, jwt

I am using JWT for authentication in the rest service. I am generating JsonWebKey to sign the token.

```
static JsonWebKey jwk = RsaJwkGenerator.generateJwk(2048);
```

When the client sends the request with the token. I'm using the JWTConsumer and the key that was used to sign the token to validate the token as below:

```
JwtConsumer jwtConsumer = new JwtConsumerBuilder()
      .setRequireExpirationTime()
      .setAllowedClockSkewInSeconds(30)
      .setRequireSubject()
      .setExpectedIssuer("techknowhub.com")
      .setVerificationKey(jwk.getPublicKey())
      .build();
try {
        //  Validate the JWT and process it to the Claims
        JwtClaims jwtClaims = jwtConsumer.processToClaims(token);
        System.out.println("JWT validation succeeded! " + jwtClaims);
      } catch (InvalidJwtException e) {
          System.out.println("JWT is Invalid: " + e);
      }
```

Right now JsonWebKey is stored in a static variable which is used for all requests. I want this key to be stored somewhere either in db / File system to be retrieved later to validate the claim.

What options are available for the same? How can I store this key object in DB?